# read array of objects from a json loop angularjs

Tags: arrays, json, angularjs

I have an object as follows:

```
var obj = {
{
  name : 'John',
  address : 'hongkong',
  company : 'hongkong pvt ltd',
  employess : [
  'Ravi', 
  'Kabhi',
  'Abhi Nahi'
  ]
},
{
  name : 'Deo',
  address : 'China',
  company : 'China pvt ltd',
  employess : [
  'Wong', 
  'kong',
  'Lee'
  ]
}
}
```

I'm accessing the object in the following way, But how do I access the array in loops.

```
 <div ng-repeat="o in obj">
    <p>{{o.name}}</p>
    <p ng-repeat="e in o.employees">
    <span>{{e}}</span>
   </p>
 </div>
```

This is how i have been doing in jade but I think angular doesn't recognize it. How can I loop through the array?

Comment: Do you mean you need something like [angular.forEach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : 
Inside your controller:

```
  $scope.obj = [
    {
        'name' : 'John',
        'address' : 'hongkong',
        'company' : 'hongkong pvt ltd',
        'employess' : [
        'Ravi',
        'Kabhi',
        'Abhi Nahi'
        ]
    },
    {
        'name' : 'Deo',
        'address' : 'China',
        'company' : 'China pvt ltd',
        'employess' : [
        'Wong',
        'kong',
        'Lee'
    ]
    }
  ];
```

On your HTML page :

```
   <div ng-controller="TempCtrl">
       <div ng-repeat="o in obj">
         <p>{{o.name}}</p>
        <hr>
        <p ng-repeat="e in o.employess track by $index">
           <span>{{e}}</span>
        </p>
        <hr>
        <hr>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`obj` should be array of object.so you have json data problem.json should be:

```
$scope.obj = [
{
  name : 'John',
  address : 'hongkong',
  company : 'hongkong pvt ltd',
  employess : [
  'Ravi', 
  'Kabhi',
  'Abhi Nahi'
  ]
},
{
  name : 'Deo',
  address : 'China',
  company : 'China pvt ltd',
  employess : [
  'Wong', 
  'kong',
  'Lee'
  ]
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Mostly it's a JSON data problem. Otherwise your code would work fine